# Making async posts requests using dictionary of items

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've built a trading bot that will buy/sell stocks as soon as the market opens and I'm trying to speed up my trade (post) requests.

I only consider about 350 stocks, but I've noticed that on days when I'm sending in a large number of orders (200-300) my requests can take quite a long time (~1.5min) when using the `requests` library.  I wanted to try to use `asyncio` and `aiohttp` in order to send in the requests faster, however I'm getting and error I can't figure out.  I'm not super familiar with async methods so I'm coming to SO for a 'lil help.

Below are the async functions for making the trade/post requests. I loosely based it on this SO answer [(python async post requests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699817/python-async-post-requests) The error I'm getting is `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable`

I'm pretty sure this has to do with trying to iterate through the dictionary, but i'm not sure how to accomplish what I want. Perhaps I need to separate the buy and sell orders so I just loop through a 2 separate lists instead of a one dictionary?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Notes**:

1. If it matters at all, the code is being executed via GCP Cloud Function.
2. Passing two lists into the function is intentional, I need to calculate buy/sell statistics prior to making the trades and thought it was easiest/cleanest to combine them in the `make_trades_async` function.

```
# Example buy/sell lists:
buySymbolsList = ['MMM', 'CLX']
sellSymbolsList = ['A' 'MS']

async def make_trades_async(buySymbolsList, sellSymbolsList, token):
    
    buyDict = dict.fromkeys(buySymbolsList, "BUY")
    sellDict = dict.fromkeys(sellSymbolsList, "SELL")
    trades_dict = {**sellDict, **buyDict}
    
    url = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/{}/orders'.format(config.MARGIN_ACCOUNT)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        post_tasks = []
        
        # prepare the coroutines that post
        async for ticker, trade_action in trades_dict.items():
            post_tasks.append(do_post(session, url, ticker, trade_action, token))
            
        # now execute them all at once
        await asyncio.gather(*post_tasks)
        


async def do_post(session, url, ticker, trade_action, token):
    async with session.post(url, 
                            json ={"orderType": "MARKET",
                                   "session": "NORMAL",
                                    "duration": "DAY",
                                    "orderStrategyType": "SINGLE",
                                    "orderLegCollection": [{
                                          "instruction": trade_action,
                                          "quantity": 1,
                                          "instrument": {
                                            "symbol": ticker,
                                            "assetType": "EQUITY"
                                          }
                                    }]
                                  },
                            headers= {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token}
                           ) as response:
        if response.status != 201:
            print("Failed to make trade for {}".format(ticker))
```

The `make_trades_async` function is run by executing:

```
asyncio.run(make_trades_async(buySymbolsList=buySymbolsList,
                              sellSymbolsList=sellSymbolsList, 
                              token=token))
```

---

**Edit**: Environment / Package information:

Python 3.7

```
asyncio==3.4.3
aiohttp==3.6.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
chardet==3.0.4
multidict==4.7.6
yarl==1.5.1
```

Comment: For the curious who come across this post...using `asyncio` reduced the amount of time to send ~250 requests from 1m30sec to 17sec, an 81% reduction in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `async` in your for loop, you are merely adding tasks to a list synchronously.  When you use `async for`, you are saying that some asynchronous code is running inside the generator that is producing your iterable. In your case, your iterable is just the list of items in the dictionary, so there's no `async` required.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you Taylor.  How can I change the code to make it asynchronous?

Comment: I think I see how to do it. Not quite sure how to pass in the other variables though with the examples I've found.

Comment: Just taking the word `async` off the beginning of the for loop doesn't work?  You don't need the for loop to be asynchronous, you are just putting all of the tasks in one place (`post_tasks`) to feed into `asyncio.gather`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the correction. I will try that this evening.

Comment: I ran into some version / environment issues as well, but ultimately this works -- removing `async` from the loop did the trick. I'll add some package and version information into my post in case it can be helpful for anyone else.  Thanks Taylor!